# How to decorate area tag in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The below code is not working. It doesn't decorate the `<area>` tag.

Is there any way to decorate the area tag ?

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #area1 {
       background-color: red;
       border-style:     solid;
       border-color:     #ff0000 #0000ff;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="kar.jpg" border="0" usemap="imgmap201522694636" alt="map"  >
  <map id="imgmap201522694636" name="imgmap201522694636">
    <area shape="rect" coords="96,66,112,80" id="area1" alt="" title="" href="" target="" >
  </map> 
</body>    
<html>
```

Comment: Are you using xhtml? If not, `/>` self closing tags is incorrect.

Comment: okay thank you.But even after removing that self closing tag it is not working.

Comment: That was just a fact, not a reason why your code isn't working. HTML treats self-closing tags as opening tags.

Comment: In HTML 5 syntax the / is fine. Pointless, but fine.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

[image: area-tag styled correctly.]

See how it has a blue/red border and a red background?

What problems are you seeing? If you have other code which is updating the area tag, you should post that here as well.

Maybe try running your code in different environments.